# Wrap the first item in array in tag and the following ones in some other tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

Ok, so let's assume i have an array of items like so [1,a,b,c].

What i'd like to achieve is to have something like this:

```html
<span>1</span>
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
```

Also it would be cool if i could assign the element a corresponding class name like class="1", class="a"...and so on.

Comment: Very much possible.. Have you tried anything which is not working as expected ?

Comment: You can use `shift()` to get the first element of the array and build the appropriate `span` from its value. Then it's a simple case of looping through the remains of the array and appending the `p` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.map()`

```
var arr = [1,"a","b","c"]; var els = ["<span/>", "<p/>"];

var elems = $.map(arr, function(value, index) {
  return $(index === 0 ? els[0] : els[1], {html:value, "class":value})[0]
});

console.log(elems);

$("body").html(elems)
```

```js
var arr = [1,"a","b","c"]; var els = ["<span/>", "<p/>"];

var elems = $.map(arr, function(value, index) {
  return $(index === 0 ? els[0] : els[1], {html:value, "class":value})[0]
});

console.log(elems);

$("body").html(elems)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using array `map`

`var array = ["1","a","b","c"];`

```
array.map(function(i,v){
    $("#someDiv").append(i == 0? "<span class='"+v+"'>"+v +"</span>" : "<p class='"+v+"'>"+v +"</p>";
});`
```